# Delegating Constructors with In-Class Member Initialization

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to do something like the following:

```
class DelegatingCTorPlusInClass
{
public:
  DelegatingCTorPlusInClass()
    :
    DelegatingCTorPlusInClass(m_a, m_b) // m_a and m_b are "random"
  {
  };

  DelegatingCTorPlusInClass(int a)
    :
    DelegatingCTorPlusInClass(a, m_b) // m_b is "random"
  {
  };

  DelegatingCTorPlusInClass(const std::string &b)
    :
    DelegatingCTorPlusInClass(m_a, b) // m_a is "random"
  {
  };

  DelegatingCTorPlusInClass(int a, const std::string &b)
    :
    m_a(a),
    m_b(b)
  {
    // DO THINGS
  };

private:
  int m_a = 42;
  std::string m_b = "42";
};
```

**However, members passed from one constructor to the other are not yet initialized so are basically "random". How could I achieve something similar then?**

Comment: I think the question is why do you want pass the members in the first place? If you don't initialize a member explicitly, it'll be initialized with the value from in-class initializer.

Comment: What do you want the values to be if they aren't specified in the constructor arguments? Pass those default values, instead of the uninitialised members, to the delegated constructor.

Comment: @jrok: I need to call the fully qualified constructor from all others.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: with default values, I would need to edit them in several places whenever they changed.

Comment: @Korchkidu: So define the default values somewhere (perhaps as static member variables) and use those, if you want to avoid duplication.

Comment: @MikeSeymour +1 that's how I'd do. As an added bonus that makes "resetting to default" way easier, and is less magic-number-esque.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: would static in-class member work?

Comment: @Korchkidu: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: excellent, thanks! I am just surprised than this is not more "known" then (static member for defaults + delegating ctors) as it seems pretty useful to me actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[class.base.init]/9`:

> If a given non-static data member has both a *brace-or-equal-initializer* and a *mem-initializer*, the initialization specified by the *mem-initializer* is performed, and the non-static data member’s *brace-or-equal-initializer* is ignored.

Which justifies that in the main constructor you assign members with garbage:

```
DelegatingCTorPlusInClass(int a, const std::string &b)
    :
    m_a(a), // this is mem-initializer for m_a, so m_a = 42 is ignored and you are getting garbage
    m_b(b) // the same for m_b
{
};
```

To avoid duplication of default values you can use constants for them, so you'll have something like:

```
DelegatingCTorPlusInClass() : DelegatingCTorPlusInClass(m_a_default, m_b_default)
{
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to build up defaults from the constructors with fewer arguments, rather than relying on inline initialization.

```
class DelegatingCTorPlusInClass
{
public:
  DelegatingCTorPlusInClass()
    :
    DelegatingCTorPlusInClass(42, "42") // default values
  {
  };

  DelegatingCTorPlusInClass(int a)
    :
    DelegatingCTorPlusInClass(a, "42") 
  {
  };

  DelegatingCTorPlusInClass(const std::string &b)
    :
    DelegatingCTorPlusInClass(42, b) 
  {
  };

  DelegatingCTorPlusInClass(int a, const std::string &b)
    :
    m_a(a),
    m_b(b)
  {
    // DO THINGS
  };

private:
  int m_a;
  std::string m_b;
};
```

A constructor should define what the value requirements are for that usage.  Inline initialization only makes sense when it is true for all constructors.

Comment: This is not what I want actually. The whole point is to avoid duplication of these default values everywhere...

Answer (score 0):

You are not required to use non-static data member initializers and delegating constructors simply because they exist. What's wrong with:

```
class DelegatingCTorPlusInClass
{
public:
  DelegatingCTorPlusInClass(int a = 42, std::string b = "42")
  : m_a(a), m_b(std::move(b))
  {
    // DO THINGS
  }

private:
  int m_a;
  std::string m_b;
};
```

Comment: how do you do if you can pass a std::string only? Then, what happens if you have not 2, but 10 parameters? Then, what happens when you need to change the default values?